# First hitting time for a brownian motion with two exponential boundaries

Tags: brownian-motion

I asked a previous related question here: [First hitting time for a brownian motion with a exponential boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490596/first-hitting-time-for-a-brownian-motion-with-a-exponential-boundary)

Now Let $B_t$ be the standard Brownian Motion. Is the distribution/density of the first hitting time of $B_t$ for two exponential decaying boundaries known?

Trying to be more formal, if

$$T=\inf\{t\geq0,\vert B_t\vert \geq e^{-\lambda t}\}$$ with $\lambda>0$, what is

$$E[T]$$

If it is known is it also known when, instead of a Brownian Motion, one has a simple Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process with mean $0$?

Thank you very much